# Error in running 'Forest-based classification and regression' tool in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, arctoolbox, typeerror

There's some problem in running the 'Forest-based classification' tool in ArcGIS Pro, which is shown as follows.

[image]

which tells me that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 11252, in execute
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSForest.py", line 7754, in execute
    created = rasterWorkFlow(*infoRasterArg)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSForest.py", line 7546, in rasterWorkFlow
    checkBalance = not hpar.balanceTree)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSForest.py", line 219, in loadDataRasterForTraining
    dataX, mask = infoRaster.extractDataFromPolygons(ssdo)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSForest.py", line 6624, in extractDataFromPolygons
    self.centroids, maskedIds = self.getCentroids(self.idCentroids, srfTo = self.srf, ids = self.polygonMask)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSForest.py", line 6495, in getCentroids
    start = NUM.int64(rangeZone[0]),
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Failed to execute (Forest).
```

I ran this tool successfully before, but in this time, I only changed the input training layer and the explanatory training raster, which are still the same type as before, and the tool failed.

Does anyone have any advice on this problem?

Comment: Can you please confirm that all your band layers are valid?

Comment: I  think My band layers are valid, they are Sentine2 data, downloaded from Scihub. I also tried two sets of data, both with modified and not modified, but all appear this problem

Comment: I think the problem is because of the Sample Layer (Input training layer). I create a new sample layer and the model run successfully. But what is quite weird is that the new sample is the same with the old one except that the new  one only include fewer polygons as I only want to try the availability.